# What's the best way to show multiple connected social media accounts in a user profile?

Tags: profile

I'm currently redesigning a member profile page and wondered if anyone had a creative way to show having multiple connected/authorized social media accounts linked to their profile. For example, I have an account on StackExchange, and I want to link 3 other social media accounts (Google+, LinkedIn, Twitter, whatever).

I'd like to show a simple way for the user to be able to add/remove one of these accounts with the least amount of clicks, and use OAuth. I'm attaching my wireframe idea for it here. Any other thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are [a lot of social networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_social_networking_websites), but only [some are popular](http://www.ebizmba.com/articles/social-networking-websites). So you could design the dialog which allows to connect to the popular platforms in a quick way, displaying appropriate buttons, and propose to select other platforms with additional control.
[image]
Connected platforms are visually distinct and ordered. This allows to perceive information faster.

The advantages are:

- Reduced information overload, as only small (reasonable) number of items are displayed
- Clear interface. `Add` and `Remove` labels create visual noise. Use tooltip instead, as the buttons thyself express affordance.
- One-click selection of a popular platform (assuming its probability)

Comment: Thoughtful input, @Alexey – very appreciated. We've decided which social networks are the most valuable/likely to be used by our specific audience, so are not too worried about showing more than a few options. This may change with time and feedback, of course. So, if there were more than a few, I do like your show/hide with "Connect to others". I also like the addition of tooltips.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, your screen is one of the most efficient that i have seen.

• The "add" and "remove" links are important to reassure the user. Maybe you can just show these on roll-over to avoid visual noise.

• 1 column list is easier to embrace all the options and make a confident choice

• if you want to cover a lot of social network, you can show the most used ones and add a dropdown for the others as suggested by Alexey

• I used to put the action buttons the right to make a cleardissociation

Good luck and please show us the final result

Comment: I would disagree with removing the add/remove links from default view. That would reduce the discoverability of these options.

Comment: Thanks, @Renaud. I currently still agree that having the simple Add/Remove prompts help with clarity; particularly with our older users (medical), where some have social channels, but are still adapting their use. Again, I do like the rollover/hover idea.